# Pandas dataframe with datetime index slices inclusively - any way to slice exclusively?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Unlike conventional slicing, datetime slicing operates a little differently

`a = df[:datetime]`

`b = df[datetime:]`

will return a single overlapping row.

Sure, I could just do `datetime + 1` millisecond on the first line,

or do `b = b.iloc[1:]`

Just wondering if there is any elegant way

Comment: Does this work `b = df[datetime:][1:]` ?

Answer (score 0):

Testing on

```
test                            
2018-03-07 19:29:48.511946    29
2018-03-08 19:29:48.511946    56
2018-03-09 19:29:48.511946    82
2018-03-10 19:29:48.511946    13
2018-03-11 19:29:48.511946    35
2018-03-12 19:29:48.511946    53
2018-03-13 19:29:48.511946    25
2018-03-14 19:29:48.511946    23
```

with

```
dt = <2018-03-13 19:29:48.511946 as datetime object>
b = df[dt:]
c = df[dt:][1:]
```

I get `b` as

```
2018-03-12 19:31:23.375432    53
2018-03-13 19:31:23.375432    25
2018-03-14 19:31:23.375432    23
```

and `c` as

```
2018-03-13 19:31:23.375432    25
2018-03-14 19:31:23.375432    23
```